# Use of function in Guard not allowed. Suggestions for alternate implementation wanted

Tags: erlang

I am attempting to create a prime number factorizer, using [fermats method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_metho).

This line generates an error

```
find_factors(A, B, FactorThis) when is_a_square(B) == true ->
```

**call to local/imported function is_a_square/1 is illegal in guard**

The only possible alternative I see to this implementation is to use some sort of case statement within the function.  I was avoiding that, as it might screw up the tail recursion.   I am a Erlang noob.  **What other ways are there to implement this functionality?**

```
get_int_part_of_sqrt(N) ->
    trunc(math:sqrt(N)).

is_a_square(N) ->
    get_int_part_of_sqrt(N) * get_int_part_of_sqrt(N) == N.

calculate_new_b(A, FactorThis) ->
    NewB = trunc(abs((A * A) - FactorThis)),
    io:format("Calculate_new_b A^2 ~w- FT ~w= NB ~w ~n",[A*A,FactorThis,NewB]),

find_factors(A, B, FactorThis) when is_a_square(B) == true ->
    io:format("find_factors true ~w ~w~n", [A, B]),
    {ok, A + get_int_part_of_sqrt(B), A - get_int_part_of_sqrt(B)};

find_factors(A, B, FactorThis) ->
    io:format("find_factors false ~w ~w~n", [A, B]),
    NewA = A + 1,
    NewB = calculate_new_b(NewA, FactorThis),
    find_factors(NewA, NewB, FactorThis).
```

[Research1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241340/unable-to-use-function-call-in-function-guard)

[Research2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505213/is-there-a-way-to-use-local-function-in-guard)

Edited.
fixed argument in call to calculate_new_b

added missing get_int_part_of_sqrts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Erlang deliberately restricts which functions you're allowed to call in guards. [Here's](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-December/054862.html) a fairly recent discussion of the justification for this, its merits and drawbacks.

The only way around it is to use `case`. You can pretty easily rewrite this code to use `case`:

```
find_factors(A, B, FactorThis) ->
    case is_a_square(B) of
        true -> io:format("      find_factors true ~w ~w~n", [A, B]),
                {ok, A + B, A - B};

        false-> io:format("      find_factors false ~w ~w~n", [A, B]),
                NewA = A + 1,
                NewB = calculate_new_b(NewA, FactorThis),
                find_factors(NewA, NewB, FactorThis).
```

Note that the above code is still properly tail-recursive.

(I modified your code a little to take out the parts that I'm guessing you meant not to have there)

Comment: Yes. This is what I was thinking of.  I removed the crap from the code in question.  It was comment residue, incorrectly removed.  Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately many of the proponents of allowing user defined functions in guards missed the point or suggested such changes to make it "safe" that it would have radically changed parts of the language.

Comment: I'll have to reread the discussion. My instinct coming from a Haskell background is to disagree and suggest that there ought to be ways to mark a function as side-effect-free (which from a Haskeller's standpoint even some of the approved functions like `node/0` and `self/0` are not) but this didn't seem like the right place.

Comment: I tried this last night, and didn't get the expected result.  I found another method of doing it.  I will try to put an edit together today, as this answer does look correct.  There is some language aspect that is invisible at the moment.

Comment: If it's a language issue related to your question, feel free to just ask :)

Comment: The code in the question was incorrect.  The calculate_new_b should have taken NewA instead of A.  Thank you Dan.

Comment: I solved the error by using new variable names for the arguments that i passed in the recursion. Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to refactor around the issue.

Add the desired guard function as an argument at the caller.  This turns it from a function with possible side effects, into true or false, which have no side effects.  Then straight pattern matching will do the job.

```
main() ->
    List2 = find_factors_2 (10, 5, 105, is_a_square(5)),
    io:format("method 2 ~w~n", [List2]).

find_factors_2(A, B, _FactorThis, true) ->
    Offset = get_int_part_of_sqrt(B),
    {A + Offset, A - Offset};

find_factors_2(A, _B, FactorThis, false) ->
    NewA = A + 1,
    NewB = calculate_new_b(NewA, FactorThis),
    find_factors_2(NewA, NewB, FactorThis, is_a_square(NewB)).
```

Comment: Yes, that would also work. The two are really equivalent, so it's a matter of aesthetic preference. I do find it interesting that *all* of the languages (to my knowledge) that support this style of pattern matching it allow it in function heads as well as in the body.

Comment: I disagree. Your solution is better, because it doesn't need the extra argument.   In effect mine is exposing a bit of the internals to the caller.  Never-the-less it is another way to do it, which may be useful to someone someday.